# how can I disable the syntax checker in ACE editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Hello I'm using the [ACE editor](http://ace.ajax.org/) and I would like to disable the syntax checker, I've found that removing the [worker-javascript.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/worker-javascript.js) file seems to do the trick but I hope there's a cleaner way as I'm not sure what else I'm disabling or even breaking by removing that file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I also didn't find this in documentation, so I've looked at ACE source code.
You can disable worker with the following lines of code:

```
var editor = ace.edit(document.getElementById('test'));
editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
```

Comment: indeed, I got a similar answer on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ace-discuss/bOovWtXhtdE

Comment: Baffling how the Ace docs don't seem to mention errors at all.

Answer (score 5):

There's a more efficient way of achieving this. Instead of spawning a worker for stopping it immediately after, is better to directly tell the editor to not spawn a worker, like this:

```
ace.edit(document.getElementById('test'), {
    useWorker: false
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **React** with the [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) wrapper you must use the `setOptions` prop to disable the ACE syntax checker:

```
  <AceEditor
    mode="css"
    theme="github"
    onChange={onChange}
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
    setOptions={{
      useWorker: false // <<----- USE THIS OPTION TO DISABLE THE SYNTAX CHECKER
    }}
  />,
```